# How to Exclude URL From PageSpeed Modification

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, google-pagespeed

I am currently working with the PageSpeed module and one of the URLs it is modifying I need to restrict.

Here is the page I am looking at but it does not seem to have the solution for restricting the URL: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls

Specifically, this is what I'm inserting into my **Apache .htaccess file**:

```
ModPagespeedAllow wildcard_spec
ModPagespeedDisallow "*//load.sumome.com/"
```

I've tried a few different combinations with no success. Any idea on how I would restrict this URL from being modified with '**pagespeed_orig_src**'?